# Custom segue to a different storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

## Question:

How might one write a custom segue that would allow you to embed view controllers from a different storyboard?

### Context:

I am trying to write a custom segue with which I can link from one storyboard to another.  A good article on [atomicobject.com](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/06/multiple-ios-storyboards/) illustrates how to create a segue that originates from a button / event etc.  Translated into swift, and allowing for non UINavigationControllers, the code looks like:

```
public class SegueToStoryboard : UIStoryboardSegue {

    private class func viewControllerInStoryBoard(identifier:String, bundle:NSBundle? = nil)
        -> UIViewController?
    {
        let boardScene = split(identifier, { $0 == "." }, maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false)
        switch boardScene.count {
        case 2:
            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: boardScene[0], bundle: bundle)
            return sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(boardScene[1]) as? UIViewController
        case 1:
            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: boardScene[0], bundle: bundle)
            return sb.instantiateInitialViewController() as? UIViewController
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    override init(identifier: String!,
        source: UIViewController,
        destination ignore: UIViewController) {
        let target = SegueToStoryboard.viewControllerInStoryBoard(identifier, bundle: nil)
        super.init(identifier: identifier, source: source,
            destination:target != nil ? target! : ignore)
    }

    public override func perform() {
        let source = self.sourceViewController as UIViewController
        let dest = self.destinationViewController as UIViewController
        source.addChildViewController(dest)
        dest.didMoveToParentViewController(source)
        source.view.addSubview(dest.view)

//      source.navigationController?.pushViewController(dest, animated: true)
    }
}
```

## Problem:

The problem that I am having with both their Obj-C and the above Swift code is that when you try to use the via a container view (with semantics of an embed segue - starting with an embed segue, deleting the segue, and then use the above custom segue), it crashes before ever calling the segue code with the following method-not-found error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIStoryboardSegueTemplate 0x7ffc8432a4f0>
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key containerView.'

I have tried to inspect the address listed but get no meaningful results.  I do the see the bold statement that it expecting the containerView but don't know how one might isolate, satisfy, and/or work around this problem.

## Summary:

My end goal is to embed view controllers defined in separate storyboards to facilitate collaboration and testing without having to write additional code (a non invasive solution).  Does anyone have any insight into how to accomplish this greater task?  I could fall back to hybrid approach of calling performSegue, but would like to find a single, contained, and complete solution.  The above code gets there for event driven (buttons etc) segues, but not with the embed segue.

Any input is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason to use a segue, as opposed to doing a presentation or push in code, is so you can see the connection in the storyboard. This is something you can't do between storyboards, so why are you trying to do it?

Comment: One reason is for layout - I can see and manage layout if I have blocks that delegate to / embed other view controllers that are used and tested in other contexts.  It also keeps the rest of my workflow consistent and is transparent and reusable.  That said, I do feel like I keep getting tempted by the forbidden fruit of auto layout and interface but it keeps biting me.

Comment: Ok, I understand now what you're trying to do. Unfortunately, I don't see any way to do this with a connection between the container view and the embedded controller. Something is going on behind the scenes with the storyboard that allows a connection from the container view, even though it is a UIView (and you can't make a segue from a "normal" UIView). The error is coming from _UIStoryboardSegueTemplate which is something we don't have access to. I think you will have to fall back on the hybrid approach making the segue from the controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach works fine for custom segues to push / display modally other view controllers but not for embed segues. The reason for this is that the "Embed" segue is not a subclass of UIStoryboardSegue but inherits from UIStoryboardSegueTemplate, which is a private API.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a better way to achieve what you want than with the hybrid approach.

Comment: Not sure about then, but in Xcode 8.2 you can use a storyboard reference with an Embed segue.

Answer (score 1):

My way is to link the containerView and delete the `viewDidLoad` segue from it. and manually call the segue on `viewdidLoad`

```
public protocol EmbeddingContainerView {
    var containerView: UIView! { get set }
}

public class CoreSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    public static func instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier: String) -> UIViewController {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Core", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self))
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier) as! UIViewController
        return controller
    }

    var isPresent = false
    var isEmbed = false
    override init!(identifier: String?, source: UIViewController, destination: UIViewController) {
        if var identifier = identifier {
            if identifier.hasPrefix("present ") {
                isPresent = true
                identifier = identifier.substringFromIndex(advance(identifier.startIndex, count("present ")))
            }
            if identifier.hasPrefix("embed ") {
                isEmbed = true
                identifier = identifier.substringFromIndex(advance(identifier.startIndex, count("embed ")))
            }
            let controller = CoreSegue.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier)
            super.init(identifier: identifier, source: source, destination: controller)
        } else {
            super.init(identifier: identifier, source: source, destination: destination)
        }
    }

    public override func perform() {
        if let source = sourceViewController as? UIViewController, dest = destinationViewController as? UIViewController {
            if isPresent {
                let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: dest)
                nav.navigationBarHidden = true // you might not need this line
                source.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else if isEmbed {
                if let contentView = (source as? EmbeddingContainerView)?.containerView {
                    source.addChildViewController(dest)
                    contentView.addSubview(dest.view)
                    dest.view.fullDimension() // which comes from one of my lib
                }
            } else {
                source.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController as! UIViewController, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and later in your code:

```
class MeViewController: UIViewController, EmbeddingContainerView {
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        performSegueWithIdentifier("embed Bookings", sender: nil)
    }
}
```